# How to recover files deleted by using foremost

Tags: debian, data-recovery

I was in the wrong folder and deleted a list of very important python files! How can I configure the rules in foremost to recover them? and using Debian O.S

```
/etc/foremost.conf

 CONFIGURATION FILE
              The configuration file is used to control what types  of
              files  foremost  searches  for.  A  sample configuration
              file, foremost.conf, is included with this distribution.
              For each file type, the configuration file describes the
              file’s extension, whether the header and footer are case
              sensitive,  the  maximum  file  size, and the header and
              footer for the file. The footer field is  optional,  but
              header, size, case sensitivity, and extension are not!

              Any  line  that begins with a pound sign is considered a
              comment and ignored. Thus, to skip a file type just  put
              a pound sign at the beginning of that line

              Headers and footers are decoded before use. To specify a
              value in hexadecimal use \x[0-f][0-f], and for octal use
              \[1-9][1-9][1-9].   Spaces  can  be  represented  by \s.
              Example: "\x4F\123\I\sCCI" decodes to "OSI CCI".

              To match any single character (aka a wildcard) use a  ?.
              If you need to search for the ? character, you will need
              to change the wildcard line *and*  every  occurrence  of
              the old wildcard character in the configuration file. Do
              not forget those h
```

but file `.py` python and `.js` javascript

Comment: There's plenty of information about recovering deleted files on Linux. If you've tried some software and ran into a specific issue, please ask about that.

Comment: check mi edit post

Comment: I'm not sure what your exact question is. Foremost does not handle Python or JavaScript files – mostly images and movies. Have you tried some of the tools in the linked question?

Comment: the question is simple, I need to create a rule for foremost so retrieve the python and javascript files

Answer (score 0):

Foremost only handles specific files like images and movies.

Out of the box, Foremost cannot recover Python or Javascript files.<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foremost_%28software%29), [2](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/data-recovery-linux-and-ext3)</sup>

However, you can make it discover additional file types, as explained [in this blog post](http://nohejl.name/2016/03/08/recovering-deleted-source-code-mac/).

For instance, by creating a `foremost.conf` file with the following tab-separated entries:

```
py  y   100000     #!/usr/bin/env\spython3
```

You can search for Python files with the suffix `py`, case-sensitive (`y`), looking up to 100000 Bytes into the header, and searching for the shebang line.